# Why am I getting this error upon calling TitleScreen instance?

Tags: c++

For some reason, when i try to call this TitleScreen instance, it gives an error. It used to work before I add a few stuff, unfortunate I can't undo it and now I have no idea how to fix it.

This is where I call the class instance: (The last line on the private section)

The errors that appears:

> Type identifier missing - int assumed. Obs. C++ does not support default-int 'tsn': Unknown substitution specifier

#### Telas.h

```
#pragma once

//Outras classes
#include "TitleScreen.h"
#include "InputManager.h"

class Telas
{
private:
    Telas();
    Telas(Telas const&);
    void operator=(Telas const&);
    InputManager input;                     //Intância do teclado
    TitleScreen tsn;                        //Instância da tela inicial

public:
    ~Telas(void);
    static Telas& GetInstance();

    void Initialize();
    void LoadContent();
    void UnloadContent();
    void Update(ALLEGRO_EVENT event);
    void Draw(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display);
};
```

#### TitleScreen.h

```
#pragma once

//Outras Classes
#include "InputManager.h"
#include "Telas.h"

//Inclusões Allegro
#include <allegro5/allegro_native_dialog.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_image.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_font.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_ttf.h>

class TitleScreen
{
private:
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP* run = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_FONT *font1 = NULL, *font2 = NULL;
    InputManager input;
    bool isDone;                    //Variável de fluxo da tela inicial
    float posx = 0;                 //Variável local de posição x
    int px;                         //Variável local de auxílio posição px
    const float posy = 530;         //Variável local de posição y
    int timer;

public:
    TitleScreen(void);
    ~TitleScreen(void);
    void LoadContents();
    void UnloadContents();
    void GameTitle(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* display);
    void GameTitleChar(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* display);
    void UpdateTimer(ALLEGRO_EVENT event);
    void SetIsDone(bool value);
    bool GetIsDone();
};
```

#### TitleScreen.cpp

```
#include "TitleScreen.h"

TitleScreen::TitleScreen(void){}
TitleScreen::~TitleScreen(void){}

void TitleScreen::LoadContents() {
    if (run == NULL) {
        px = 0;
        timer = 0;
        run = al_load_bitmap("Sprite_Run_Full.png");
        if (!run) {
            al_show_native_message_box(NULL, "Erro", "Erro", "Sprite não carregado", NULL, NULL);
        }
    }
    if (font1 == NULL) {
        font1 = al_load_ttf_font("Fonte1.ttf", 70, NULL);
        if (!font1) {
            al_show_native_message_box(NULL, "Erro", "Erro", "Fonte1 não carregada", NULL, NULL);
        }
    }
    if (font2 == NULL) {
        font2 = al_load_ttf_font("Fonte1.ttf", 20, NULL);
        if (!font2) {
            al_show_native_message_box(NULL, "Erro", "Erro", "Fonte2 não carregada", NULL, NULL);
        }
    }
}

void TitleScreen::UnloadContents() {
    if (run != NULL) {
        al_destroy_bitmap(run);
    }
    if (font1 != NULL) {
        al_destroy_font(font1);
    }
    if (font2 != NULL) {
        al_destroy_font(font2);
    }
}

void TitleScreen::GameTitle(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* display) {
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgba_f(1, 0.714, 0.757, 0));
    al_draw_text(font1, al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0), al_get_display_width(display) / 2, 100, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE, "Kirbry's Game");
    al_draw_text(font2, al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0), al_get_display_width(display) / 2, 200, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE, "Press Enter");
}

void TitleScreen::GameTitleChar(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* display){
    posx = (160 * px) / 60;
    if (timer % 30 >= 0 && timer % 30 < 30 / 5) {
        al_draw_bitmap_region(run, 0, 0, 44, 50, posx, posy, 0);
    }
    if (timer % 30 >= 30 / 5 && timer % 30 < 2 * 30 / 5) {
        al_draw_bitmap_region(run, 44, 0, 44, 50, posx, posy, 0);
    }
    if (timer % 30 >= 2 * 30 / 5 && timer % 30 < 3 * 30 / 5) {
        al_draw_bitmap_region(run, 88, 0, 44, 50, posx, posy, 0);
    }
    if (timer % 30 >= 3 * 30 / 5 && timer % 30 < 4 * 30 / 5) {
        al_draw_bitmap_region(run, 132, 0, 44, 50, posx, posy, 0);
    }
    if (timer % 30 >= 4 * 30 / 5 && timer % 30 < 5 * 30 / 5) {
        al_draw_bitmap_region(run, 176, 0, 44, 50, posx, posy, 0);
    }
}

void TitleScreen::UpdateTimer(ALLEGRO_EVENT event) {
    if (event.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER) {
        if (timer < 60) {
            timer++;
        }
        else {
            timer = 0;
        }
        if (px > 300) {
            px = -17;
        }
        else {
            px++;
        }
    }
}

void TitleScreen::SetIsDone(bool value){
    isDone = value;
}

bool TitleScreen::GetIsDone(){
    return isDone;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a loop in your #includes:

- Telas.h includes TitleScreen.h
- TitleScreen.h includes Telas.h

Read [Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes) for more details.

That being said, it's not clear why TitleScreen.h needs to include Telas.h.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the assignment operator: it returns the result, so it can't be declared as `void`.
Change the line:
`void operator=(Telas const&);`
to
`Telas& operator=(Telas const&);`
then fix the implementation of this operator.

Comment: Oh, actually I should've take that part out. I got it from a tutorial, but it was meant to be used later there. It was just defined but not called on the code, I just commented it now.

Comment: Unfortunate, the error is still the same :/

Comment: I'll post the TitleScreen code here, maybe the error is there